# Un problema con promesas

Tags: javascript, promesas

Estoy tratando de insertar los valores que obtengo de un JSON a través de un fetch en los elementos que voy creando dinámicamente en el DOM.

Aquí tengo la función que lee dicho JSON:

```
function fetchUrl(url){
            fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: new Headers({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }),
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => insertData(data));
        }
```

La cual llama a la función insertData(data) con el JSON ya parseado:

```
async function insertData(data){
            let domTitle        = document.getElementById('main-title-input');
            let domDescription  = document.getElementById('main-description');
            let domUrl          = document.getElementById('main-url-input');
            let btn             = document.getElementById('addInp');
            let lnk             = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
            let chk             = document.querySelector('input[name=doLinkedin]');
            let event           = new Event('change');

            if(data.imgs.length > 0){
                for(let i = 0; i < data.imgs.length; i++){

                    if(data.imgs[i].title){
                        chk.checked = true;
                    }
/*
                    let promise = await createElements(btn)
                    .then(()=>{
                        document.querySelectorAll('.link')[i].value = data.imgs[i].url;
                        document.querySelectorAll('.link')[i].dispatchEvent(event);
                        
                        if(data.imgs[i].title){
                            document.querySelectorAll('.title-linkedin')[i].value = data.imgs[i].title;
                        } else {
                            document.querySelectorAll('.title-linkedin')[i].value = '';
                        }
                        
                        if(data.imgs[i].description){
                            document.querySelectorAll('.description-linkedin')[i].value = data.imgs[i].description;
                        } else {
                            document.querySelectorAll('.description-linkedin')[i].value = '';
                        }
                    });
*/

                    createElements(btn);
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        document.querySelectorAll('.link')[i].value = data.imgs[i].url;
                        document.querySelectorAll('.link')[i].dispatchEvent(event);
                        
                        if(data.imgs[i].title){
                            document.querySelectorAll('.title-linkedin')[i].value = data.imgs[i].title;
                        } else {
                            document.querySelectorAll('.title-linkedin')[i].value = '';
                        }
                        
                        if(data.imgs[i].description){
                            document.querySelectorAll('.description-linkedin')[i].value = data.imgs[i].description;
                        } else {
                            document.querySelectorAll('.description-linkedin')[i].value = '';
                        }
                    },150);
                         
                }
            }

            domTitle.value          = data.title;
            domDescription.value    = data.description;
            domUrl.value            = data.url;
        }
```

Dicha función tiene comentado el cómo pretendo realizar dicha promesa, y sin comentar, el parche que tengo para ver qué resultado tendría que dar con el setTimeout, el cual, quiero suprimir.

insertData hace una llamada a createElement que hace lo siguiente:

```
async function createElements(b){
            let elm = document.getElementById('dv-coord');
            let input = [
                {
                    type: 'input',
                    name: 'link',
                    addClass: 'link vcp-login-form-action-bottom vcp-wrapper',
                    onCreate: function (a, b){
                        b.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
                            setCoords(b);
                        });
                    }
                },
                {
                    type: 'button',
                    name: 'delete_input',
                    addClass: 'deleteInput vcp-wrapper',
                    label: 'X',
                    onCreate: function(a, b){
                        b.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
                            eraseCoords(b);
                        });
                    }
                },
            ];
            let cord = [
                {
                    type: 'box',
                    id: 'img-coord',
                    addClass: 'id-coord',
                    content: [
                        {
                            type: 'textarea',
                            addClass: 'xy-txt',
                            id: 'txt-coord',
                            name: 'coord-x-y'
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'input',
                            addClass: 'inpchk',
                            name: 'inp-check',
                            disabled: true,
                            placeholder: 'Click on image...'
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'container',
                            id: 'hashtags-list',
                            addClass: 'list',
                            content: []
                        }
                    ],
                    onCreate : function(a,b){

                        let img = document.createElement('img');
                            img.setAttribute('class', 'photo-coord');
                            img.style.width = '500px';
                            img.style.height = '500px';
                        b.insertBefore(img, b.firstChild);
                        getLinkedinChecked(b);
                    }
                }
            ];
            ui.parser(input, b.parentNode);
            ui.parser(cord, elm);
        }
```

Donde ui.parser solamente es un append, solo que un poco complejo.
parametro1.append(parametro2).

```
async parser(jsonContent, node){
        let self=this, type, m;
        self.parserArray(jsonContent);
        for( const n in self.modulesListPrev){
            type =  '_' + n ;
            m = await import('./js/modules/'+ type + '.js').then(Module => {
                self.modulesList[type] = Module[type];
            });
        }
        self.displayElement(jsonContent, node);
        return  new Promise(function (resolve, reject){ 
            resolve(self);
            return self;
        });
    }
```

Cómo podría hacer la promesa correctamente de insertData?

Comment: y si usas el onload del dom?

Comment: Ya probé, pero tampoco me sale al final. Esa función a la que llamo la llamo desde varios sitios, y con esta promesa, intento crear elementos directamente en el DOM para meterlos valores dentro. Si cambio algo de dicha creación, tendría que modificar la entrada de la función de todas las veces que la llame.

Comment: En esta pregunta falta código para entender el problema: sin la función createElements no podemos ver cómo se crea y resuelve la promesa que has creado. Del mismo modo, en el primer código, sin saber qué se ejecuta con el click en el botón tampoco podremos saber por qué es necesario el setTimeout

Comment: Edito, ya que además hacer el click del botón hace la misma función, había cambiado eso después de preguntar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La función `createElements` está declarada como `async`, pero no veo que se haga uso de await o promesas en su interior. Creo que el problema viene porque dentro esta función se hace uso de asincronía y no se está teniendo en cuenta.

Mi hipótesis:

La función `createElements` tiene este aspecto cuando la resumimos un poco para fijarnos en ciertos detalles:

```
async function createElements(b) {
    let elm = document.getElementById('dv-coord');
    let input = [ ... ];
    let cord = [
        {
            type: 'box',
            id: 'img-coord',
            addClass: 'id-coord',
            content: [
                ...
            onCreate: function (a, b) {
                ...
            }
        }
    ];
    ui.parser(input, b.parentNode);
    ui.parser(cord, elm);
}
```

La clave está en esa función `onCreate` que pasamos a `ui.parser`: claramente es un callback, por lo que podrías hacer algo como:

```
function createElements(b) {
  return new Promise(completada => {
    let elm = document.getElementById('dv-coord');
    let input = [ ... ];
    let cord = [
        {
            type: 'box',
            id: 'img-coord',
            addClass: 'id-coord',
            content: [
                ...
            onCreate: function (a, b) {
              let img = document.createElement('img');
              img.setAttribute('class', 'photo-coord');
              img.style.width = '500px';
              img.style.height = '500px';
              b.insertBefore(img, b.firstChild);
              getLinkedinChecked(b);
              completada(); // <- resolviendo la promesa!!
            }
        }
    ];
    ui.parser(input, b.parentNode);
    ui.parser(cord, elm);
}
```

Y entonces sí podrías hacer algo como

```
createElements(...).then(....)
```

Comment: Habiendo puesto la resolución de la promesa "completada();" tal donde tu la pones, no me crea las imágenes, es decir, me crea el elemento, pero no lo inserta en el DOM. Poniéndolo detrás de "ui.parser(cord, elm);", inserta las imagenes, pero no inserta valores ya que no los encuentra. E insertando un then después den mismo parser, con la resolución, tampoco inserta los valores que necesito en los elementos del DOM. Es decir, NUNCA llega a ver los elementos del DOM incluso después de hacer un then a su propia inserción en este...